# Optimizing images to generate gifs

Tags: javascript

I am using a library that generates n number of frames entering 2 images.My problem is after generating the frames.

I am trying to generate gifs(gif.js) with and optimize the times to generate them. I am trying to achieve this for mobile phones with the help of the IONIC framework, so I should optimize as much as possible. I have a problem when I run my application. The generation of gifs is delayed even more than the algorithm itself to generate frames. I am trying to add 60 frames, I have made a console.log(gif.frames) and I see that all the saved images are as base64 I am not sure if this influences for this procedure to take longer.

All the images, I have compressed them with software to have jpg images of around 10-12kb.

I do it with this piece of code and size 280px x 280px.

```
var gif = new GIF({
  workers: 2,
  quality: 10
});

var res_c = document.getElementById("result");
var res_ctx = res_c.getContext('2d');

var frames = animator.frames; //60 images in format imageData, 60 frames
for (var x = 0; x < frames.length; x++) {
    res_ctx.putImageData(frames[x],0,0);
    gif.addFrame(res_c,{copy:true,delay: 50});
}

gif.render();
```